# How do I colour text without spaces?

Tags: sectioning, color

I want to colour my section and subsection headings. I've used the following code

```
\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\section{Section}} 
\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\subsection{Subsection 1.1}}
```

but that causes a large gap between the section and subsection headings as below:

[image]

How do I get rid of the gap?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\section{Section}}

\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\subsection{Subsection 1.1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using any packages (other than, say, [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor))? Can you provide us with a minimal document that we can use to start with? It should replicate your current setup (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: `\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}    
\begin{document}  
\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\section{Section}}   
\textcolor{ForestGreen}{\subsection{Subsection 1.1}}  
\end{document}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid the verbatim formatting of sectional units within your document. Rather use hooks that tap into the sectional unit formatting. This allows you to change things at the document level while maintaining readable code.

[`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) provides sectional unit font hooks through (for example) `\sectionfont` and `\subsectionfont`. The following example shows how to do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\sectionfont{\color{ForestGreen}}% Add to default \Large\bfseries
\subsectionfont{\color{ForestGreen}}% Add to default \large\bfseries

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection 1.1}

\end{document}
```

The default formatting for `\section`s are `\Large\bfseries`, while `\subsection`s are `\large\bfseries`. You'll note that I've only added `\color{ForestGreen}` to those defaults.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. I added the defaults by default... :-|

Comment: What exactly is a hook?

Comment: @MonzurRahman: A hook is a generic term that refers to a piece of code (typically a single macro/command) that has been inserted in specific positions of other, larger macros/commands. These hooks might be defines as no-ops (they do nothing), but it allows you to redefine them at the document level, and they'll have effect throughout your document. It's a way to "hook" (or tap) into certain attributes of document elements.

Comment: @MonzurRahman: [`sectsty`](//ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) inserts a number of hooks into the sectional units' elements that set the actual titles. So, instead of "patching" or entirely redefining (copying from the `\documentclass`, say) the sectional units, now you just have to load the package and change the hooks. The package itself does all the redefining (and insertion of hooks).